# Power shell script for Monitoring C-Drive

Tags: monitoring, powershell-5.0

```
# find the path to the desktop folder:

 $desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

 #specify the path to the folder you want to monitor:

 $Path = $desktop

# specify which files you want to monitor
$FileFilter = '*'  

# specify whether you want to monitor subfolders as well:
$IncludeSubfolders = $true

# specify the file or folder properties you want to monitor:
$AttributeFilter = [IO.NotifyFilters]::FileName, [IO.NotifyFilters]::LastWrite 

# specify the type of changes you want to monitor:
$ChangeTypes = [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Created, [System.IO.WatcherChangeTypes]::Deleted

# specify the maximum time (in milliseconds) you want to wait for changes:
$Timeout = 1000

# define a function that gets called for every change:
function Invoke-SomeAction
{
  param
  (
    [Parameter(Mandatory)]
    [System.IO.WaitForChangedResult]
    $ChangeInformation
  )
  
  Write-Warning 'Change detected:'
  $ChangeInformation | Out-String | Write-Host -ForegroundColor DarkYellow


}

# use a try...finally construct to release the
# filesystemwatcher once the loop is aborted
# by pressing CTRL+C

try
{
  Write-Warning "FileSystemWatcher is monitoring $Path"
  
  # create a filesystemwatcher object
  $watcher = New-Object -TypeName IO.FileSystemWatcher -ArgumentList $Path, $FileFilter -Property @{
    IncludeSubdirectories = $IncludeSubfolders
    NotifyFilter = $AttributeFilter
  }
```

I have to monitor the C-Drive whether any software is installed or uninstall the above script will give details if any software is installed or uninstalled it has to display the message saying that the particular software is installed or uninstalled with date , but i am not able to scan the c drive but Desktop folder is scanning. please let me know how to scan the c drive and notice the changes. I have used GetFolderPath() function.

Comment: sir i tried $Path = "C:\" i am getting error as cannot convert value "C: \" to type "system.environment+special folder" Error: unable to match the identifier name C: \ to a valid enumerator name

Answer (score 0):

Your script literally starts with declaring the path:

```
# find the path to the desktop folder:

 $desktop = [Environment]::GetFolderPath('Desktop')

 #specify the path to the folder you want to monitor:

 $Path = $desktop
```

So if you alter this to `$Path = "C:\"` it should work.

Comment: Sir @LPChip is probably right as to your initial problem but it doesn't change the fact that this is a horrible/impossible way to try to do what you are trying to do.  So ANY addition or deletion of a file will notify your script and your script will try to figure out if it is an installation or not?  This will be horrible code at best and lock up your system at worst.  What will your script do if it thinks it IS an install?  What will your script do concurrently while dealing with that install when another change notification arrives?

Comment: @SeñorCMasMas Oh, I totally agree with you here, but given that the answer to this question was so simple, I figured that OP is strugling enough and just chosen to answer it, rather than ask for more details that probably deviates from a solution even further.

Comment: Of course @LPChip , you and I agree 100%.  I was only pointing out that the solution to his problem (which you provided) was not going to get the OP to the goal line :)  What the OP is trying to solve is not a simple problem to be done in a script.  Windows has policies for this written by engineers and even THOSE don't work very well (for obvious reasons.. see "what IS an installer?").

Comment: Oh I know all too well, @SeñorCMasMas. Tried to block installers using GPO to find out that some software installs without installers (spotify, chrome, etc...)